# Jobs: there is a bug on the list of benefits offered by a company

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a problem with the list of benetfit offered by a company in the job offering page.

I see this:

[image]

As you can see the position of elements of the list is wrong.
I'm using Firefox 44.0.2 on a MacBook Pro, I've tested the issue using Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit), Opera 35.0 and Safari 9.0.3 (11601.4.4) but the bug is visible only on Firefox.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/108447/full-stack-developer-sql-java-ee-javascript-ptv-sistema?offset=2&distanceunits=Km&location=rome&range=20) is the link of the job offering I'm talking about.

Comment: Link to the posting please. So we can see if we also experience the same issue

Comment: @JustDoIt I've added the link ;-)

Comment: Replicated on Firefox 44.0.2  and on IE 11.0.9600.18205 (Win 8.1)

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't test this issue on IE because I'm currently on a Mac with OSX.

Comment: That's why added it :) on chrome shows the list just fine like you said

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The fix will be live in the next prod build.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the classic [css - two inline-block, width 50% elements don't stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871996/css-two-inline-block-width-50-elements-dont-stack) issue. It looks like they are using a `display: table` hack to try to counter it, a hack I'm not familiar with and is apparently not cross-browser.

```
div.company-page .benefits-list {
    display: table;
}
```

Disabling this rule in the Chrome inspector causes Chrome to render it the same as other browsers.

It looks like they were using floats to handle this at least at some point, so perhaps the rule was just lost at some point. Adding this CSS fixes the issue.

```
div.company-page .benefits-list .benefit {
    float: left;
}
```